Disable Android view's auto scroll when height changed
I have just found Android scrollable view(Webview, recyclerview...) has auto scroll behavior when the height is changed (e.g. rotation changing android:configChanges=orientation options).
For example:

Rotation portrait, screen shows contents 2~4 and scroll left-top position is 2. (1 [2 3 4] 5).
Rotation changed to landscape, screen shows only two contents.
At this point, auto scroll triggered to set scroll left-top position to 2. (1 [2 3] 4 5).

I assume step 3 is Android default behavior, but how can I turn off this "auto scroll"?
Is it possible to disable the "auto scroll" when the scrollable view's height is changed?
